# How to change background transparency of xterm

Tags: gnome-terminal, customization, desktop-background, xterm

In terminal we can change the background transparency by changing the slider in

```
edit>preference>background>transparent background
```

Similarly how can we change the transparency of xterm background

Comment: You might try http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xcompmgr/ xcompmgr, which is compositor only (not window manager)

Comment: AFAIK, xterm can't have transparent background. You can change color and font size but not transparency

Answer (score 2):

xterm doesn't have built in transparency, from what I know. You may be able to use a compositing window manager to change the transparency of an xterm window, but I think you'll be hard pressed to do it natively in xterm.